# ParseException: u"\nextraneous input '/' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD',

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to read header files and corresponding `csv` from a directory, while writing csv's to `pyspark dataframe` throws error

> ParseException: u"\nextraneous input '/' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM',
>   'ADD',  IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL
>   ==\n/persistent/4G/filtered_week1/cell_res\n^^^\n"

My piece of code is attached here:

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here`

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '8g'), 
                                        ('spark.executor.cores', '2'), 
                                        ('spark.cores.max', '10'), 
                                        ('spark.driver.memory','8g')])
spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .config(conf=conf)\
                    .appName("Mergecsv mbnl")\
                    .getOrCreate()
indir="/persistent/4G/filtered_week1/"
#outfile = "/persistent/4G/week1_15Feb/Untitled Folder"
csv_seperator=','
header= glob.glob(indir + "/*.header")
all_files = glob.glob(indir+ "/*.csv")
        for filename in all_files:
         for head in header:
            x= head.split('.sql')[0]
            if x in filename:
                df1=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").schema(x).load(filename)
                df1.take(1)`
```

Comment: "indir" has a "/" at the end, and in glob, you again have /*.csv. So, you can avoid one. Also, is it a problem with both reading and writing the CSV file, or one only with writing?

Comment: its still giing same error while writing to dataframe. after making changes

Comment: Are you sure about the last line df1.take(1)` (which ends with a `)?

Comment: it is not there in code

Comment: i need to write header from a file and than while writing csv to dataframe needs that header to be attached with records